# Permission j2me application, removing the prompt

Tags: java-me, permissions, sign

I have a signed application for Nokia 2660.

This application makes HTTP connections and when the application is opened the device prompts a message asking for user permission.

The user can previously opening the application make a configuration so that this prompt never appear.

This works fine.

When a new version of the application is installed this configuration made by the user is lost and he has to make it again.

Is there a way to avoid re-configuring the application?

Any suggestions? Do you know any workaround?

Answer (score -2):

One thing I can think of is to save this configuration on server, and ship the app with a "config option" flag. On first download or an overwrite of the existing application, the app starts and sees that this "config option" flag is not set, checks with the server if the configuration is saved there, if it is, then it is downloaded and saved to rms. Else the user is prompted to create a configuration, which is then saved to rms and server.

The "config option" flag can be as simple as say a unique string saved to rms.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case, I suspect the prompt comes from the phone security policy, as part of the midp runtime. It's not something that can be accessed from the application.